# cosmosdb emulator mongo connection string Error: Slash in host identifier

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to connect my NodeJs application with the CosmosDb emulator in localhost:

[image]

Since in my azure resouce group I am created a cosmodb instance of kind MongoDB

[image]

I am using the following connection string to test it in localhost:

mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true

unfortunatelly seems that the connection string provided doesn't fit very well...

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The account key in the Mongo URL must be URL encoded. We should be doing this for you in the Web UI. I’ll add this as an issue to address in the next data explorer update.

Comment: It works! I just copy the key(password) part and encode it online (https://www.urlencoder.org/), paste it back to the connection string, working now.